# JSON datetime between bash script and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, bash, couchdb

In the same spirit as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455580/json-datetime-between-python-and-javascript/2680060#2680060), is there a recommended way to generate / parse dates from within a bash script so that it can be interfaced to Javascript `Date`?

To be precise, I get this strings when doing json encoding of a Javascript Date object:

```
2011-10-31T10:23:47.278Z
```

I could put together a bash hack to generate / parse that date format, but I would prefer to avoid reinventing the wheel. Does somebody have a working solution?

I am more interested in the "generating" side: I want to generate current dates from a bash script and save them in a json document (couchdb) so that they can be automatically ordered by the view engine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest I am coming is this:

```
date -u +"%FT%T.000Z"
```

Which gives this output:

```
2011-11-03T06:43:08.000Z
```

I do not like that I have to put the `T`, the `Z` and the milliseconds to 0 manually (I can use `%N` for nanoseconds, and truncate with `sed` or whatever, but seems like overkill just to get millisecond precission), and I was hoping that there would be a built-in format token for `date` which would produce that UTC date. I assumed - wrongly it seems - that the format is common enough that it can be specified with just one format token.

Comment: You can get actual nanoseconds truncated with the following (tested on CentOS 6.4):

`date -u +"%FT%T.%3NZ"`

That appends the current nanoseconds truncated to three characters.  Here's some example output: `2015-05-11T19:18:54.021Z`

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can convert many different values into dates. Not sure if that's what you mean, but for example. Your bash could generate this string: "2011/11/10 08:08:08"

When it gets to JavaScript land you can do this

```
var date = new Date("2011/11/10 08:08:08")
```

You can also do this:

```
var now = 1320287813362
var date = new Date(now)
```

More info on what Date accepts here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Other interesting info here:
[What's the best way to store datetimes (timestamps) in CouchDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812235/whats-the-best-way-to-store-datetimes-timestamps-in-couchdb)

Comment: I understand that your suggested format `2011/11/10 08:08:08` is easy to generate and sorts ok. But to tell you the truth, I am not sure I would be covering all corner cases (summer / winter time, timezones, and whatnot) with that format. I would really prefer to stick to the format `2011-10-31T10:23:47.278Z`, which gives me peace of mind. And the reason I ask is that I would like to use a pre-existing format string to `date` (or similar tool), so that I am not reinventing the wheel here.