# dates in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

How do you insert dates in couchdb? As strings?

I have couchdb-1.0.3.

1.

I did this:

```
$ curl -X PUT 127.0.0.1:5984/misc/doc1  -d '{"date":"2011-13-01T17:30:12+01:00"}'
```

This works, but this date doesn't exists.

2.

I thought I had to do this:

```
$ curl -X PUT 127.0.0.1:5984/misc/doc1  -d '{"date":new Date("2011-12-01)}'
```

But this is invalid JSON.

3.

When I use this format,

```
$ curl -X PUT 127.0.0.1:5984/misc/doc1  -d '{"date":"2011/12/01 00:00:00"}'
```

I doesn't work well with this format

```
$ curl -X GET '127.0.0.1:5984/misc/_design/foo/_view/view1?startkey="2012-02-02"'
```

Because the document shows up in the result.

Thanks,

Eric J.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use your first format, or possibly the [JSON2 standard format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812235/whats-the-best-way-to-store-datetimes-timestamps-in-couchdb), which is most convenient for JavaScript. That is what most people do, and it works well with your example request:

```
$ curl '127.0.0.1:5984/misc/_design/foo/_view/view1?startkey="2012-02-02"'
```

To *validate* your data, use a [validation function](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/validation.html).

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I tried, but maybe you can tell me why I get an JSON error message when I do: curl -X PUT 127.0.0.1:5984/misc/doc1 -d '{"date":JSON.stringify(new Date)}'

Comment: That is Javascript, not JSON.

Comment: Thanks again. I understand. So how do you create documents with a date in it? (Just a simple example would be great)

Comment: No problem! But would you mind posting a fresh question? To me, this question here is more about "what is the best date syntax" but your next question sounds like "how should I create dates: server-side, client-side, which programming languages, etc. etc." Of course, only you know the specific questions you need to know.