# How to search and sort with CouchDB in one map function

Tags: couchdb

I'm stumbling a bit with my CouchDB knowledge.

I have a database of content that is tagged with an array of tags and has a created date.

I want to create a view that pulls a limited number of newest stories tagged with a specific tag.

For example, the newest 6 stories tagged "Business."

Ran across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773069/sorting-dates-in-couchdb-views), which seems to get me almost to where I need to go, but I'm missing one key element, which I think is how to craft the query string to sort by one key while searching by the other.

Here's my map function.

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.published == "yes" && doc.type == "news") {
        for (var i = 0; i < doc.tags.length; i++) {
            if (doc.tags[i]) {
                emit([doc.created, doc.tags[i]], doc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So how do I query that view for a all documents tagged "Business" that are the newest documents based on created.

The created attribute is a date sortable format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would switch the order of your emit:

```
emit([doc.tags[i], doc.created]);
```

*(leave out `doc` as well, you can just add `include_docs=true` to get the entire document, and your view won't take up so much disk-space in the process)*

Now you can query for the all the stories tagged as `"Business"` by using the following querystring:

```
startkey=["Business"]&endkey=["Business",{}]
```

You'll get all the documents with the tag business, and they'll be sorted by date.

This takes advantage of [view collation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation), which basically is the rules governing how indexes are sorted/queried. For complex keys like this, the sorting is done for each item of the array *separately*. (ie. the first key is sorted first, the second key is sorted second, etc) This is why the order matters, as you must always move from left to right when querying a view index.

If you want the 6 most recent, your querystring will need to change:

```
descending=true&limit=6&endkey=["Business"]&startkey=["Business",{}]
```

**NOTICE** You need to swap the `startkey`/`endkey` values, due to how the `descending` parameter works. See the [View reference page on the wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API) for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured this out, but I'm not quite certain I fully understand it.

I found [this story](http://ryankirkman.github.com/2011/03/30/advanced-filtering-with-couchdb-views.html) about complex keys and searching and sorting.

My map function looks like this:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.published == "yes" && doc.type == "news") {
        for (var i = 0; i < doc.tags.length; i++) {
            if (doc.tags[i]) {
                emit([doc.tags[i], doc.created], doc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to query and sort using it, the query looks like this.

http://localhost:5984/database/_design/story/_view/tagged?limit=10&startkey=["Business"]&endkey=["Business",{}]&descending=false

I'm getting the results I want, but I'm not entirely certain I understand it all.

Comment: I'll add more explanation to my answer